# Recompiling code while program execution

Tags: c++, c, makefile

If I have a series of C/C++ programs that I need to build using Make , would it mess up the code run if I made changes to the code and recompiled while the program is executing an executable? Or is all the information preloaded in the executable before runtime?

Thanks.

Comment: You usually have to restart your debug session. There are some restrictions to overwrite running programs on Windows OS IIRC.

Comment: The answer depends on the OS you are using. In Linux/Unix/MacOS, any file can be "replaced" at any time with a new file of the same name - the old file remains in place until it is closed (but will no longer appear in the directory listing). On VAX/VMS, a new version of the file is created, so that's fine too (as long as you have file versioning enabled). On Windows, it won't work, as you will be trying to write to the same executable as is open to execute the file.

Comment: Probably depends on your platform. Is it so hard to run from a different copy?

Comment: @Mats Petersson, Are you sure about Linux? I recall that when I by mistake launched make while debugging it just failed to create an executable. But I am not quite sure. Perhaps it might matter that I did it inside Eclipse CDT.

Comment: @skwllsp Depends on implementation and context again. Could well be that debuggers lock an executable binary while debugging sessions are active.

Comment: @skwllsp: I quite often use `make` inside gdb whilst the application is still running, and that certainly works.

Comment: There is no language "C/C++". But there are the two **different** alnguages C and C++.

Comment: @skwllsp: Absolutely works on Linux. Our current system runs in a loop controlled by a bash script. So we often just re-build in place. The running application is not affected and will continue to run until completion. When the bash script executes the application again it will pick up the new version. We run ubuntu but should work on all linux like systems.

Comment: Even if you don't recompile the code if you make changes to it while debugging the debug information will be out of sync and you may not be able to hit the correct breakpoints or step through the correct code.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: On linux systems the debugger will spot that and ask you if you want to reload the new version of the executable.

Answer (score 0):

This depends entirely on whatever operating system you're using.

Linux is perfectly happy continuing to execute a program whose binary has been removed, and replaced with a new binary.

It is my understanding that Microsoft Windows is, on the other hand, rather grumpy in the same situation, and won't be happy if something like this is attempted.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly, you can edit the code while you run the program and the program will not change while you run it.